# Cannot convert access token to JSON

Tags: java, jdbc, oauth, token, spring-cloud

I'm using Oauth2.0 in spring cloud, my authorization server,  im storing the token in the database **using jdbcTokenStore** instead of JwtTokenStore and its working properly, but when i make a http request, postman returns this error.
{
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "Cannot convert access token to JSON"
}
so it's because I havent implement the method **accesstokenconverter**

I've been looking for how to implement this method but i havent been lucky yet.
can you help me guys

```
package com.restaurants.serviciooauth.security;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
 private  BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    //configuration to jdbc
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
       security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
       .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
     clients.inMemory().withClient("frontendapp")
             .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
             .scopes("read","write")
     .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
     .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
     .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
             .and()
             .withClient("androidapp")
             .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
             .scopes("read","write")
             .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
             .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
             .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }


}
```